# Issue with rounding

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

I am really new to python and having difficulty with this issue.
I have to take the following information from a data frame and provide its mean [ the answer is suppose to return a single number]

Here is the column from the data frame:

```
   Country
China                  93.0
United States         286.0
Japan                 149.0
United Kingdom        124.0
Russian Federation    214.0
Canada                296.0
Germany               165.0
India                  26.0
France                166.0
South Korea           221.0
Italy                 109.0
Spain                 106.0
Iran                  119.0
Australia             231.0
Brazil                 59.0
Name: Energy Supply per Capita, dtype: float64
```

Now using the following:

```
Per_capita = Top15.loc[:,['Energy Supply per Capita']].mean()
Per_capita.iloc[0]
```

I get:

```
157.59999999999999
```

so I tried using the `round` function:

```
Per_capita = Per_capita.round(decimals = 1)
```

I still get the same output if I have any decimal places. It only changes when I put decimals to 0 and it gives 158 which I am assuming is not the answer they are looking for.

if I do not use the iloc function I get a nice 1 decimal answer though

```
Energy Supply per Capita    157.6
```

i want to get a 2 decimal answer for the above

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is there a question in there that I missed?

Comment: sorry about that, i am looking for a 2 decimal answer to the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue of rounding; it's an issue of display. The number 157.6 is not exactly representable in double precision arithmetics, its representative double-precision number is slightly less than 157.6. Python floats and NumPy floats  differ in how to deal with this issue when displaying numbers in the console. Example:

```
x = 157.6
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [x]})
y = df.iloc[0,0]
```

Now if you type `x` in the console, you get 157.6, but if you type `y`, you get 157.59999999999999. Yet, `x == y` is True. What's the deal?

Different types, that's all: x is a Python float, y is a NumPy float, since it came from a dataframe (pandas uses NumPy under the hood). Hence the **cosmetic** differences in appearances. The numbers are the same, there is nothing for rounding to do.

How to avoid the ugly 9s: use `print(y)`, or in your example, `print(Per_capita.iloc[0])`. The print function will present the floats in a nice way, be they NumPy floats or Python floats.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it. But the grader still shows the answer as incorrect. Oh well no clue what more i can do.

Comment: You can also convert to a  Python float with `float(Per_capita.iloc[0])` though I don't know how the grader works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are solving coursera assignment. Just use following code if the answer should be number without any decimals:

```
Per_capita = int(Top15.mean())
```

If you need the answer to be 157.6 use:

```
Per_capita = Top15.mean()
```

Comment: So the Top15 is the dataframe, i want to use a particular column. So i used :
`code`Top15['Energy Supply per Capita'].mean()

.Still getting the same value

Comment: the mean() function can be called both on a Series and a Data Frame in pandas. It would be helpful if you edit your question to include full information of your dataframe

Answer (score 0):

this maybe related with the data 157.59999999999999

take example as follow:

b=157.59999999999999

print np.round(b,decimals=0)

print np.round(b,decimals=1)

print np.round(b,decimals=4)

> > 158.0
> >
> > 157.6
> >
> > 157.6

if change the value of b:

b=157.5932321231341231

print np.round(b,decimals=0)

print np.round(b,decimals=1)

print np.round(b,decimals=2)

> > 158.0
> >
> > 157.6
> >
> > 157.59

this time is working, so this maybe depend on the data,.999999

for the data, the result for decimals=2,3,4, all the result are the same.